# Retrieve XML from URL and Parse with JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml, cross-domain

I would like to retrieve XML from a URL and parse it with JQuery.  I am working under the assumption that a different domain without cross domain access cannot be accessed with AJAX.  Therefore, I have created a PHP code to return it (I don't understand how this is something we have to deal with in 2015, but maybe I'm just dumb):

```
header('Content-Type:xml');
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22375842?report=xml");
$xmlstring = $xmlDoc->saveXML($xmlDoc->documentElement);
print $xmlstring;
```

Now I am using an AJAX function to call that data:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "loadXML.php", //+ searchString,
  dataType: "xml",
  type: "GET",
  success: parseXml
});
```

Finally, here is my parseXML function, which has been tested with local XML pages and works fine.  This code has been repeated on SO many times:

```
function parseXml(xml){
  $(xml).find("Article").each(function()
  {
    $("#output").append($(this).attr("PubModel") + "<br />");
    $("#ArticleTitle").append(": " + $(this).find("ArticleTitle").text() + "<br />");
  });

  $(xml).find("Author").each(function()
  {
    $("#Author").append(": " + $(this).find("LastName").text());
    $("#Author").append(", " + $(this).find("ForeName").text());
  });
};
```

Nothing happens.  Somebody for the love of Zeus please help me... and go easy, I'm apparently not understanding how to do something pretty simple to begin with.  I thought about saving the data on the PHP page to a local file on my server, but it couldn't handle "<" and ">".  I'm a little lost here.

Comment: Add `console.log(xml);` in the `parseXml` function and post the result.

Comment: The correct way to set up the content type header is `header("Content-Type: text/xml")`

Comment: added console.log(xml); in the parseXml function and nothing changed.  Also corrected the content type header.

Answer (score 0):

Opening the URL in the browser the result content is not really XML, but escaped XML in a `<pre>` tag.

Snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<pre>
&lt;PubmedArticle&gt;
    &lt;MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE"&gt;
        &lt;PMID Version="1"&gt;22375842&lt;/PMID&gt;
        &lt;DateCreated&gt;
        ...
```

To output the content as XML you need to echo the text content of the document element:

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22375842?report=xml");

header('Content-type: application/xml');
print $xmlDoc->documentElement->textContent;
```

Comment: THANKS.  I COULD KISS YOU.

Comment: P.S: Before, the output looked like XML, so I never thought to change that.  Now the output is just regular text. so I had no idea that was formatted correctly.  Damn dude.  It looks like regular text, but that's because HTML hides the tags I guess.  If you inspect the page all the information is there.

Comment: I'd like to thank ThW's parents for creating him, also the internet for its existence.  I'd also like to thank the creator of SO.

Comment: :-) How the browser renders it depends on the browser and the content type. With `application/xml` or `text/xml` many browser will render it in a XML view. But if they render it as web page, they will ignore the unknown tags and just display the text content.